# Function works only on 1 marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My problem here is that function `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function()` works only then I click first marker. Clicking on all other markers has no effect. I want this function to be working on all markers. What's the problem here?

```
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            MyApp.xxx = this.position;
            infowindow.setContent('x' + name[i][3] + '' + name[i][4] + 'x');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

var markerroad;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () {

    var request = {
        origin: MyApp.xxx,
        destination: 'Kaunas',
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    })
}));
```

Comment: do the other markers exist on load or are they added after? If so, you need `.on('click')` instead of `.click()` which only binds nodes that are present when it runs.

Comment: There is no more code for generating markers apart the code above.

Comment: Why is your second `google.maps.events.addListener` outside of your `for` loop?

Comment: @user1876234 Did that fix it? Moving it to inside the loop? I'll create an answer if that fixed it

Comment: Yes, that fixed that!

Comment: @user1876234 I added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't including the second `addListener` in the loop. Try this:

```
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            MyApp.xxx = this.position;
            infowindow.setContent('x' + name[i][3] + '' + name[i][4] + 'x');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var request = {
            origin: MyApp.xxx,
            destination: 'Kaunas',
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Since both `addListener` calls are for the same item (`marker`), you could probably combine the code in each function so that there's only one `addListener` call.